# Android multiple column list/grid with adapter and OnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, list, onclick, adapter

I have a simple grid with rows of items and columns of options on each item. Of course I can manually link OnClick actions to cell items through specific resource IDs:

```
 views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.row1column1, launchA);
 views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.row1column2, launchB);
    // ...
 views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.row2column1, launchC);
    // ...
```

What I'd prefer to to is use a ListView or a GridView and an Adapter.  Is there a way to get cell id's from one of those?  I was hoping that ListView setOnItemClickListener() would call me with the view id of a view within row 'position':

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { ... }
```

but no go.  Maybe a different approach?

Thanks.

Update:

I started with this:

```
contactsView.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact, contacts));
contactsLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ... });
```

I'd assumed that I couldn't go into my Adapter and set child view OnClickListeners.  Bad assumption.  When I went back at this I gave it a try:

```
Button x  = (Button)newView.findViewById(R.id.contact_x);
Button y = (Button)newView.findViewById(R.id.contact_y);
x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });
y.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });
...
```

Voila!

Comment: P.S>  I earned 1000 views badge with this question.. if you find it useful please support the SO process by marking the question -  click the UP triangle.. ty!